# cursor disappears during touch screen mode

Tags: windows-10

I'm using HP EliteDisplay S230tm Touch monitor with windows 10 and I have this problem that whenever I enable touch screen mode the cursor disappears from the screen and then I have to move the mouse physically as to know where cursor is present on the screen. Is there any settings through which I can fix this problem or any latest drivers that I can install for fixing it.

Thank you:)

Comment: This is the default behavior. While your finger acts as a pointer, it doesn't not behave in precisely the same way the mouse pointer does, and so Windows hides the mouse cursor when you use the touchscreen, and then reveals it again when you move the mouse. If the mouse cursor did not hide, it would be precisely where your finger last pressed the screen. Is this an actual problem, or is it just an annoyance?

Comment: It is an actual problem for me because I'm using OBS studio which switches screen based on cursor position, so whenever I want to switch screen I touch on screen as to get cursor there instead of moving mouse again and again.

Answer (score 0):

As of January 31st there is no way to show the mouse cursor while touching the screen: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-touch/show-mouse-cursor-also-when-using-touch-screen/e9a7ab79-baeb-4b47-afee-4d8fed4cfbcb

> We're glad to know that you want to maximize the feature of your
>   Windows 10 computer. However, the option that you want to have the
>   cursor visible while on the touchscreen mode is not yet available.

The linked post goes on to recommend using the Feedback app to suggest this feature (or find others who have suggested it and upvote their suggestions).